# TypeError in if else statement

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I keep getting this error:

```
if AR_GCC<16 and AR_GCC>0:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

It is a program that is supposed to print the cancer risk according to the input of the user (not a real thing just for practice)

This is the piece of code that doesn't work:

```
AR_GCC=input("AR_GCC repeat copy number?")

if (AR_GCC>0 and AR_GCC<16):
        risk="High risk"
elif (AR_GCC >= 16):
        risk = "Medium risk"
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

Comment: Where are you having trouble?  `input` returns a string.  You try to compare it to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the input is interpreted as number. Simply adding `int()` before the `input` function should solve that. Of course if the value passed is a string, it will fail. Therefore your code should be: 
`AR_GCC=int(input("AR_GCC repeat copy number"))` should do the trick. Sorry for formatting, typing from phone